# Rewriting values in a rasterlayer in R by condition

Tags: r, raster

I got myself a rasterlayer called "prah" containing values ranging from 60 to 210. And my question is pretty simple, I would like to replace all values smaller than 100 by 100. It means, that I want the smallest value in the layer to be 100.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example that includes some example data from the raster package.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=61:160)
```

Solutions

```
x <- clamp(r, 100)
#or 
y <- reclassify(r, cbind(-Inf, 100, 100))
```

With this toy example you can also do

```
r[r < 100] <- 100
```

But that is not the approach you should generally take for scripts; as it is inefficient and prone to memory problems.